# How can I configure multiple location from using Nginx Rewrite or Regex etc

Tags: regex, nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse

I am a new user at Nginx.

I do not want to enter all the location paths one by one.

Here is my conf. I need to do, when I enter itech.com/api/[enter a path], reverse proxy must pass my request to the valid web site.

What should I do on the following configuration to do this?

Thanks for your help,
Regards,

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  xtest.com;

location /api/hrpm {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}

location /api/hrpm/periods {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/hrpm/periods;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  api.html index.htm;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that your question has an answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite

Comment: It is also explained quite clearly here: https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/

Comment: What do you mean by "the valid web site"? Currently you are routing `/api/hrpm` to `www.intercitywebsocket.com` and `/api/hrpm/periods` to `localhost:5000`. What are you trying to change?

Comment: @Richard Smith sorry for config, I changed it